# How to copy files in an svn repo to another folder on the server

Tags: linux, svn, svn-repository

Running a centos 6 server with svn repos stored on it. To deploy updates, I'd like to copy from the relevant directory within the svn repo to the appropriate /var/www website directory. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Does this server contain working copies or the main repos? If it does have the main repo you can easily leverage post-commit scripts (which detect a tag commit or what not) and do the 'cp' or 'svn switch' command.  The same approach can work when the the svn repos is hosted from a different server, but this requires some additional remote auth and cmd access/setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `svn export` command to do that. The [subversion red book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.c.export) explains in detail how to do that.

When the relevant svn repo is stored under `/export/svn/repo`, and the part of the repository you want to copy from is `/trunk/my_project/news`, the whole command will be:

```
svn export file:///export/svn/repo/trunk/my_project/news /var/www/news
```